# Find the expression for $f(x)$ an expression for $f(g(x))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic

I fail to understand something fundamental about universal statements and sets.

Suppose we have a function $f$, such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\:f(\frac34x)=2x^2$

I want to find the expression for $f(x)$.

$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\: \exists x'=\frac34x$. Substitute $x'$ into the function to get $f(x')=\frac{32x'^2}{9}$, and it would seem that I can substitute $x'$ to $x$ getting $f(x)=\frac{32x^2}{9}$, but why? With this substitution I'm replacing the whole domain of $f$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to the set $\left\{ x' | x'=\frac34x, x \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$. Should I now show that the set of all $x'$ equals $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You have asked a good question.  The answer is yes, but that's because the range of the function $g(x)=\frac 34 x$ is all of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Might be a good idea to look at for example the same function given on lets say $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.  Your work so far proves that $f(x')=32x'^2/9$ for all $x'$ such that $x'=3x/4$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  This only completely determines $f$ if you can prove that every $x'$ in the domain of $f$ (which I assume is supposed to be $\mathbb{R}$) actually can be written as $3x/4$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

The following alternative example may be instructive.  Suppose you have a function $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x^2)=2x^2$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  Then you *cannot* conclude that $g(x)=2x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  You can only conclude this for such $x$ that are the square of a real number, i.e. for $x\geq 0$.  You have no information at all about the value of $g(x)$ if $x<0$.

Answer (score 2):

That's a notation play. Just rewrite it: $f\left(\dfrac{3x}{4}\right) = \dfrac{32}{9}\cdot\left(\dfrac{3x}{4}\right)^2\implies f(x) = \dfrac{32}{9}x^2$.